# How can I reference a helm array parameter with index

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have this helm parameters in a values.yaml file.

```
spec:
   containers: 
     - name: mycontainer
       image: my.image.url
```

I would like to reference the name and image parameters from another kubernetes-resource.yaml file with index.

I tried

```
containerReference: {{ index .Values.spec.containers[0].name | quote }}
```

and

```
containerReference: {{ (index .Values.spec.containers 0).name | quote }}
```

But I get: bad character U+002D '-'

Comment: Can you give a little more complete example?  What command are you running that produces that error?  (There's almost no `-` in what you've shown.)

Comment: kubernetes-resource.yaml is a k8s resource yaml in templates directory. The values.yaml is the standard helm values.yam. The error is triggered with helm install

Comment: Are you able to access other values? I am wondering because I think it should be `.Values` instead of `.Value`.

Comment: This is a typo, I am fixing right now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
{{ with index .Values.spec.containers 0 }}
containerReference: {{ .name | quote }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: How to pass the same through helm command for overriding?